# Problem with encode decode. Python. Django. BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, beautifulsoup

In this code:

```
   soup=BeautifulSoup(program.Description.encode('utf-8'))
   name=soup.find('div',{'class':'head'})
   print name.string.decode('utf-8')
```

error happening when i'm trying to print or save to database.

dosnt metter what i'm doing:

```
print name.string.encode('utf-8')
```

or just

```
 print name.string


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 16, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/cluster/dynamic/virtualenv/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 362, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/cluster/dynamic/virtualenv/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/cluster/dynamic/virtualenv/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 195, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/cluster/dynamic/virtualenv/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 222, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/cluster/dynamic/website/video/remmedia/management/commands/remmedia.py", line 50, in handle
    self.FirstTimeLoad()
  File "/usr/local/cluster/dynamic/website/video/remmedia/management/commands/remmedia.py", line 115, in FirstTimeLoad
    print name.string.decode('utf-8')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 2-5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is repr(name.string)

u'\u0412\u044b\u043f\u0443\u0441\u043a \u043e\u0442 27 \u0434\u0435\u043a\u0430\u0431\u0440\u044f'

Comment: Please post the output of `print(repr(name.string))`, and `print(sys.stdout.encoding)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do with `name.string.decode('utf-8')`. As the BeautifulSoup documentation [eloquently points out](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html), "BeautifulSoup gives you Unicode, dammit". So `name.string` is already decoded - it is in unicode. You can **encode** it back to utf-8 if you want to, but you can't decode it any further.

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
print name.string.encode('ascii', 'replace')
```

The output should be accepted whatever the encoding of `sys.stdout` is (including None).

In fact, the file-like object that you are printing to might not accept UTF-8.  Here is an example: if you have the apparently benign program

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print u"hérisson"
```

then running it in a terminal that can print accented characters works fine:

```
lebigot@weinberg /tmp % python2.5 test.py 
hérisson
```

but printing to a standard output connected to a Unix pipe does not:

```
lebigot@weinberg /tmp % python2.5 test.py | cat
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
print u"hérisson"
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

because `sys.stdout` has encoding `None`, in this case: Python considers that the program that reads through the pipe should receive ASCII, and the printing fails because ASCII cannot represent the word that we want to print.  A solution like the one above solves the problem.

Note: You can check the encoding of your standard output with:

```
print sys.stdout.encoding
```

This can help you debug encoding problems.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: `name.string` comes from BeautifulSoup, so it is presumably already a unicode string.

However, your error message mentions 'ascii':

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 2-5:
ordinal not in range(128)
```

According to the [PrintFails Python wiki page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails), if Python does not know or
can not determine what kind of encoding your output device is expecting, it sets
sys.stdout.encoding to `None` and `print` attempts to encode its arguments with
the 'ascii' codec.

I believe this is the cause of your problem. You can can confirm this by seeing
if `print sys.stdout.encoding` prints `None`.

According to the same page, linked above, you can circumvent the problem by
explicitly telling Python what encoding to use. You do that be wrapping
sys.stdout in an instance of `StreamWriter`:

For example, you could try adding

```
import sys
import locale
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter(locale.getpreferredencoding())(sys.stdout)
```

to your script before the `print` statement. You may have to change
`locale.getpreferredencoding()` to and explicit encoding (e.g. 'utf-8',
'cp1252', etc.). The right encoding to use depends on your output device. 
It should be set to whatever encoding your output device is expecting. If
you are outputing to a terminal, the terminal may have a menu setting to allow
the user to set what type of encoding the terminal should expect.

**Original answer:** Try:

```
 print name.string
```

or

```
 print name.string.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Already tried not help. The interesting thing is that in python 2.6.5 it works. And 2.5.2 not.....

Answer (score -1):

try

```
text = text.decode("utf-8", "replace")
```